# Does Windows 11 synchronise installed apps so that you can restore system or switch to a new PC quickly?

Tags: windows, windows-11, sync

I'm trying to keep everything in sync principally through the Microsoft account, including To Do tasks, Windows settings and more so that I don't have to set up everything again everytime I do a system restore or switch to a new PC.

However, I'm having to keep a list of apps that I've to manually install in a cloud document since Windows won't install (at least some of) them automatically. If I use the Microsoft Store to install apps, will I have to worry about installing them manually next setup?

Comment: Yes, Windows has done this since, Microsoft Accounts could be linked to a local Windows user account. To be specific it will redownload UWP applications you have installed from the Microsoft (Windows) Store.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a lot different than any App.  If you want a complete backup you need to make one.

The Windows Apps, Office, Adobe and a few other can be installed in 60 to 120 minutes on a new build, so I just do it that way and keep my data backed up.

Your Microsoft Account sets up very quickly because Microsoft keeps some stuff in the cloud.

So make your own backup, or know where your App sources are.